Wordpress: How to add additional field in a form for submitting posts by users and assign it to the correct taxonomy?
I have the free version of the User Submitted Posts plugin that lets user create Wordpress posts. It has one dropdown for the category of the post, however, I need a second one where users choose a location. I've set "location" as a taxonomy. I used JS in my Code snippets plugin to transform one of the free text fields to a dropdown that displays the "location" options, however, the location choice that the user makes when filling the form isn't assigned to the published post. The post has nothing in the location category. Please help me achieve this with code as I can't afford Premium plugins at the moment. This is the JS code:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Target the custom field by its ID
    const customField = document.getElementById('user-submitted-custom');

    if (customField) {
        // Create a new select element
        const locationDropdown = document.createElement('select');
        locationDropdown.setAttribute('id', 'user-submitted-location');
        locationDropdown.setAttribute('name', 'usp_custom_field'); // Same name as the original input
        locationDropdown.setAttribute('data-required', 'true');
        locationDropdown.required = true;
        locationDropdown.classList.add('usp-input');

        // Fetch terms from the 'location' taxonomy
        fetch('/wp-json/wp/v2/location?per_page=100')
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(locations => {
                // Add a default placeholder option
                const defaultOption = new Option('Select a Location', '', true, false);
                locationDropdown.add(defaultOption);

                // Add location terms as options
                locations.forEach(location => {
                    const option = new Option(location.name, location.id);
                    locationDropdown.add(option);
                });

                // Replace the original input field with the dropdown
                customField.replaceWith(locationDropdown);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching locations:', error);
            });
    } else {
        console.error('Custom field not found!');
    }
});


I don't know how to achieve it, I asked ChatGPT which provided this PHP snippet but it didn't work:
add_action('usp_post_submit', 'assign_custom_taxonomies', 10, 2);
function assign_custom_taxonomies($post_id, $data) {
    // Check if location field exists and assign terms
    if (!empty($data['usp_custom_field'])) {
        $locations = array_map('intval', (array) $data['usp_custom_field']); // Ensure it's an array of integers
        wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $locations, 'location');
    }
}

